# Hibernate JPA Meta Model -- reference nested properties?

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria-api

Suppose an entity model where an `Employee` has a `Supervisor` who has an `id`. Using `hibernate-jpamodelgen` to generate the meta model for the entities, how can I query a nested field?

For instance, "get all employees whose supervisor has id 4", using `JpaSpecificationExecutor`:

```java
Page<Employee> getEmployeesBySupervisorId(int id) {
  return findAll((root, query, criteriaBuilder) -> {
    return criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get(Employee_.supervisor.id), id);
  });
}
```

Note that `Employee_` is the model meta class for `Employee` (and was generated by Hibernate).

This code will produce an error because the `id` symbol cannot be found on type `SingularAttribute<Employee, Supervisor>`. I get that, but it seems like these should somehow be chainable. I can't find great examples of how to do this cleanly.

Comment: In order to navigate to related entities, you must use [From#join()](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/criteria/From.html#join(javax.persistence.metamodel.CollectionAttribute)) join method, which works well with MetaModel as explained in [Oracle's JAVA EE Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjivm.html)

Comment: I figured that out -- if you want to add an answer, I'll accept. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to navigate to related entities, you must use [`From#join()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/criteria/From.html#join(javax.persistence.metamodel.CollectionAttribute)) join method, which works well with MetaModel:

```
CriteriaQuery<Employee> cq = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(Employee.class);
Root<Employee> from = cq.from(Employee.class);
Predicate p = criteriaBuilder.equal(from.join(Employee_.supervisor).get(Supervisor_.id), id);
```

**See also**

[Oracle's Java EE Tutorial - Using the Criteria API and Metamodel API to Create Basic Typesafe Queries](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjivm.html)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I also stumbled upon this problem that the Metamodel classes are not offering deeper visibility to relationships > 1.
While accessing A.b is possible, A.b.c is not.

But there is another possibility besides Joins:
Just concatenate by using several getter(). For this you will need a root element (= CriteriaQuery & CriteriaBuilder).

```
return criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get(Employee_.supervisor).get(Supervisor_.id), id);
```

While this still ensures type safety, the whole path should be correct as it is not validated until runtime.

Also for sorting a resultset using the Metamodel there is a similar solution. Say you want to sort by the Supervisor's id:
Use JpaSort and JpaSort.Path

```
JpaSort.of(JpaSort.Direction.ASC, JpaSort.path(Employee_.supervisor).dot(Supervisor_.id));
```